# Url error in smartpy

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, nft, python, tezos-base

I trying to write a smart contract on the tezos network and using `import FA2 library` for this. But when I try to run the code I face the url error.
this is my code :

```
import smartpy as sp

FA2 = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py") 

class CyrusNft(FA2.Fa2Nft):
    pass
    
@sp.add_test(name="Test cyrusNft")
def test():
    sc = sp.test_scenario()
    cyrusNft = CyrusNft(metadata=sp.utils.metadata_of_url("ipfs://Qme5jKLzvtLfgQowJqPExWw9sJHrbwYqRgKTtxgJEjfHDG"))
    sc += cyrusNft
```

and this is error :

```
In /lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py, line 1419:

raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError:
```

thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sp.io.import_template("fa2_lib.py")`.

Answer (score 0):

The updated URL for importing the FA2 library is `https://legacy.smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py`

You can get the latest info from [the official docs](https://legacy.smartpy.io/docs/guides/FA/FA2/overview)

Here is the final code:

```
import smartpy as sp

FA2 = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://legacy.smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py")

class CyrusNft(FA2.Fa2Nft):
    pass

@sp.add_test(name="Test cyrusNft")
def test():
    sc = sp.test_scenario()
    cyrusNft = CyrusNft(
        metadata=sp.utils.metadata_of_url(
            "ipfs://Qme5jKLzvtLfgQowJqPExWw9sJHrbwYqRgKTtxgJEjfHDG"
        )
    )
    sc += cyrusNft
```

Comment: I replace the https://legacy.smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py but still get same error!

Comment: @AMSSAL Are you able to directly open this URL in the browser? If not, what error is it showing in the console?